# Tufte Latex Class - First chapter has no number

Tags: chapters, tufte

I'm starting to get a little desperate. My first chapter has no number and I can't figure out why.

To get chapter numbers I used `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` . This works perfectly for every chapter, except for the first. I haven't used anything other as for the other chapters.

```
\chapter{Test1} -> no Number -> "Test1"

 several sections and subsections

\chapter{Test2} -> Results in "1 Test2"
```

I tried

```
\chapter{Test}

some text

\chapter{Test1}

 several sections and subsections

\chapter{Test2}
```

and this resulted in Test and Test1 having no number and Test2 having again the number 1.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

The same problem appears in the standard Tufte Sample Book (`\documentclass{tufte-book}`), which is available [here](https://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/downloads/detail?name=tufte-latex-3.5.0.zip&can=2&q=). I removed the star from the Introduction chapter:

```
\chapter*{Introduction} -> \chapter{Introduction}
```

and added `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`. This yields chapter numbers for all chapters, except for the first one.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: As Henri states, we need more information, with `\documentclass{tufte-book}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}\begin{document}\chapter{Test}\chapter{Test2}\end{document}` I get numbers on both chapters, so we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Have you put `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` before `\begin{document}` (in preamble)?

Comment: @HarishKumar Yes I added it directly under \documentclass{tufte-book} .

Comment: Is your first chapter before `\mainmatter`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for your advice. The code is really long and I'm not sure if I should add it here completely. The code is avaliable here https://tufte-latex.googlecode.com/git/sample-book.tex and I only added \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} below \documentclass{tufte-book} and removed the star from the Introduction chapter.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce it. You have to a your code in the form of a MWE. Otherwise we are clueless.

Comment: You should in general never post complete code, you should first remove everything that does not influence the issue. This is the process of making an MWE.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The chapter was indeed before \mainmatter ! Putting it behind solves my problem. Thank you, thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess your first chapter is part of the frontmatter, i.e. it is placed between `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. In the `\frontmatter` chapters are unnumbered, as demonstrated by this example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
  \chapter{Test}
\mainmatter
  \chapter{Test2}
\end{document}
```

Hence, just move your first chapter after `\mainmatter` to solve the issue.